# WebSocket is missing from agent settings in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, websocket, agent

I have installed the `Websocket Notifier` and `Websocket in Notification plugin`. I also installed the Kubernetes plugins though I dont think they are really needed for this.Then I went to `Configure System` and saw that `Websocket Notifier` was there with a port number. There was a box next to it that says `status format` so I checked it off because it doesn't seem like it can hurt me. I made sure that I didnt need to include the websocket anywhere else by looking at `Configure Global Security` and `Global Tool Configuration` but they looked good to me. So I go to `Configure` for my Agent settings and gave it a name with the number of executors with the remote root directory along with the usage and launch method. My understanding was that the option `Use Websocket` was supposed to be below `Fail if workspace is missing` column and I can't figure out why it isn't there. I have seen it before on someone else's Jenkins which means that I am either still missing something or I forgot to configure something else that will allow me to use the websocket. Maybe I'm not properly using the Websocket port number and need to enable it somewhere like the `Global Tool Configuration` etc. Maybe I need to mess around with the TCP Port. There was this documentation called `JEP-222 WebSocket Support for Jenkins Remoting and CLI` I read but it didn't really give me information that was helpful to this case

[image]

Comment: Could be multiple things. I guess you're jenkins version is above 2.222 if you're using LTS branch? It was introduced on  2.222. If yes have you tried to restart the jenkins service on the slave computer so that it pulls the latest remoting jars? If yes, are there any errors in the log while booting jenkins master?

Comment: @Joschi funny because it was because I needed to updated and it didnt give me that option before!

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins [WebSocket protocol](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/02/02/web-socket/) to connect agent is recent and may still suffer from bugs even it is now the [recommended method](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-setup-guide/configure-ports-jnlp-agents).

So it is important to update your Jenkins version and search for known defects

- https://www.jenkins.io/changelog-stable/
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61851
- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62576